# How do I send a message to all Actors in an Akka Router?

Tags: java, akka

How do send a message to all Routees/Actors in an akka.routing.Router?

Note: I'm using Java not Scala

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a broadcast message, as shown in the docs:

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.10/java/routing.html#broadcast-messages-java